# Как проверить что запрос пришёл от VK?

Tags: php

Допустим при авторизации с виджета VK, в php файл приходят GET запросы с параметрами о данных юзера. Как мне проверить что запрос пришёл именно от вконтакте, а не от маминого хакера?

Comment: При авторизации тебе придёт токен, нет?

Comment: там максимум хэш юзера, я даже хз чё с ним можно сделать)

Comment: что такое "хэш юзера"?

Comment: `hash (string) — служебный параметр, необходимый для проверки авторизации на удаленной стороне.`